# Unbound DataGridView issue

Tags: data-binding, datagridview

I am able to write to my unbound datagridview (VC++), but am unable to read back that same exact value.  So I can do this:

```
myDataGridView[0,0]->Value = 1 ;
```

And this updates my display correctly.

But I can't do this:

```
printf("value=%d\n", myDataGridView[0,0]->Value ;
```

It compiles, but regardless of which cell I read, and regardless if I have ever written to it or not, I always read the same value (8?).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear when you write "regardless of which cell I read, and regardless if I have ever written to it or not, I always read the same value." Have you tried this? C# example:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()
```